# Weird Nuxt layout behaving

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I am using nuxt 3 in my project, and I want to use custom layout, but every time I use

```js
definePageMeta({ layout: "custom" });
```

I got this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'subTree')
>
> at move (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js:6414:1)
> at move (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js:6428:1)
> at move (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js:6414:1)
> at move (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js:6414:1)
> at move (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js:6428:1)
> at move (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js:6414:1)
> at Object.resolve (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js:2592:1)
> at unmountComponent (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js:6575:1)
> at unmount (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js:6478:1)
> at patchKeyedChildren (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js:6375:1)

It is weird because when I use

```js
setPageLayout("custom")
```

everything works as it should. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Can you share you  folder structure or more details about code.Because check out the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fp151i?file=pages%2Findex.vue) here it's working fine